# jQuery converting selectors to negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am sorry if this is really a novice question, but I am not very practiced in JS syntax.

I am having a small syntax problem, where I need to convert this working function

```
   jQuery('div.myclass').filter('[aria-describedby*="DDD"], [aria-describedby*="CCC"]').hide()
```

into a negative one ( meaning hiding when NOT containing `DDD` and `CCC`.

I tried

```
 jQuery('div.myclass').filter().not('[aria-describedby*="DDD"], [aria-describedby*="CCC"]').hide()
```

and

```
 jQuery('div.myclass').filter(:not'[aria-describedby*="DDD"]', :not'[aria-describedby*="CCC"]').hide()
```

I am aware it is probably a novice syntax problem, But I can not find the right syntax when combined with these selectors and the filter() function

Comment: `jQuery('div.myclass').not('[aria-describedby*="DDD"],[aria-describedby*="CCC"]').hide()`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `.not()` function?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LxnAP/1/

Answer (score 2):

No need of `.filter()` directly use [**.not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
jQuery('div.myclass').not('[aria-describedby*="DDD"],[aria-describedby*="CCC"]').hide()
```

Comment: my god.. I can swear I tried that one before ... Now it is working. must be another syntax error .

Comment: @krembo99 yeah might be. But good thing is that it's working now .